# How can i override the default magento cms homepage entry with a custom module?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, module, overriding

I am currently attempting to use a custom module as the first page when you hit the magento installation, i currently have {{block type="namespace_module/block" template"path/to/template.phtml"}} located within the home page cms entry, but unfortunately it is not calling the template or the module which i am requesting, i am now looking at trying to find out if its possible to use a custom module (controlled by indexController.php) to take precidence over the cms home page entry.

This has two reasons behind it, reason 1, it will give me more flexibility for me to extend the index page, and 2, it will allow me more flexibility over css/js which i want to include on that specific page.

If anyone knows of a solution to getting a custom module to take precidence over the cms home page it would be a huge help to myself and the community at large as many people are un-aware of how this is achieved.

Thanks for any assistance provided.
Ryan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a custom controller then put it's [frontname/controller/action](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento#3) path in *System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages > Default Web URL*.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, been looking for this option for a while.